# How to set blockstates in minecraft 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you set blockstates in 1.13? E.g how do you set a lever's face to be floor?

I have tried `/setblock x y z lever{blockState:{face:"floor"}}`, also `/setblock x y z lever{Properties:{face:"floor"}}`.

I probably sound quite dumb, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blockstates in 1.13 are specified in square brackets after ID, e.g:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ lever[face=floor]
```

Multiple blockstates can be separated with commas.

The tab-completion for blockstates in 1.13 is also helpful:

[image: Blockstate tab-completion]